# Image Skew Transformation with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of some coins. however, they are at an angle.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omw58.jpg) I am trying to perform skew image transformation to achieve something like this. (ignore the shadow and the rotation) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNIfZ.jpg)

I have the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omw58.jpg) as a NumPy array in RGB format. I am unsure of what to do with it next. Assuming I don't have the access to [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNIfZ.jpg).

Is it even possible to achieve this without using an untilted image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNIfZ.jpg).

Comment: Without a reference image or camera model and only the shape of the coins, it will be a bit hard to even estimate the correction.

Comment: You will have to estimate the pitch, roll and yaw angles from the orientation of the white background paper upon which they sit. Then form your own homography matrix.

Comment: @fmw42 can I do this with a reference image. What if so can you give me a code snippet.

Comment: You need to be able to find 4 pairs of corresponding points between your image and the reference image in order to do that. Then you can use warpPerspective after finding the homography from the 4 pairs of corresponding points.